# Check what connections a software / application is trying to make

Tags: network-monitoring, wireshark

How to check what urls and ports a particular application or software is trying to access? Does it require Wireshark of something?

Comment: I believe you can (and should) do this out of the box from a command line...

Comment: The two methods given here -> http://shallowsky.com/blog/linux/monitor-net-connections.html work very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `netstat` for monitoring your network traffic.
Use the following command to monitor network connections and applications using network:

```
sudo netstat -p
```

The output will be similar to this format:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State PID/Program name
```

Use `man netstat` for more information on using netstat.

Comment: This does not show what urls or IP address the process is trying to connect to.